# Understanding cryptic C++ statement

Tags: c++, arduino, reinterpret-cast

I come from .NET programming using VB.NET and this is my first C development for an Arduino based application.

Reading through the Arduino header files (looking for something like a `.ToString` method for the `__FlashStringHelper`) I stumbled upon the next `#define`

```
#define F(string_literal) (reinterpret_cast<const __FlashStringHelper *>(PSTR(string_literal)))
```

First what I understand:

This is a macro with a parameter named `string_literal` and this parameter is somehow used in the expression inside parenthesis. That's all!

What are these `<`, `>` signs and that `*` pointer sign all of a sudden?

Comment: Wrong language. That's C++, not C. I've edited the title and tag.

Comment: You can read about `reinterpret_cast` [for example here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast). In short, it's the C++ variant of C-style casts.

Comment: Terminology hint: `#define` is called a *preprocessing directive*, and the whole line a *macro definition* (for the function-like macro `F`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**General type casting**
In C++, there are various types of casts which can be used to convert between types. They are important because C++ is a strongly typed language, and the compiler doesn't necessarily know that any given conversion between types is safe or sensible. By default, it will issue an error or a warning unless you explicitly tell it what to do.

All of the C++ casts have the following format:

```
x_cast <new_type> (expression)
```

`x_cast` can be one of the following: `static_cast`, `dynamic_cast`, `reinterpret_cast`, or `const_cast`.

A reinterpret cast is used when you want to force the compiler to convert between unrelated pointer types. The result is a pointer to exactly the same piece of data in memory. However, it will be handled (or interpreted) as though it's a different type, which can allow some interesting operations.

For example, let's say you have a pointer to a 4 byte unsigned integer, and you want to access each byte individually. You could do that by reinterpreting the pointer to a 1 byte type, like this:

```
uint32_t num = 12345;
uint32_t *p1 = &num;

uint8_t *p2 = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(p1);

// Access the individual bytes:
uint8_t byte0 = p2[0];
uint8_t byte1 = p2[1];
uint8_t byte2 = p2[2];
uint8_t byte3 = p2[3];
```

Pointers `p1` and `p2` both point to the data stored in the `num` variable. The difference is that accessing it via `p2` will result in the compiler treating it like a 1 byte unsigned integer (instead of the original 4 byte type). This lets you extract/manipulate individual bytes at different locations within the original variable.

For a simple example like this, `reinterpret_cast` is quite safe. However, there are many situations where it can go very badly wrong, or simply do nothing useful, if it's not used carefully. An example would be trying to reinterpret a `float` pointer as an `int`. On its own, it won't do anything bad. The result will be completely useless though, because the underlying binary representation of a `float` doesn't make sense if you try to handle it like an `int`.

The same approach can work for objects, letting you interpret an instance of one class as though it's an instance of a different one. However, it doesn't do any intelligent conversion. It simply forces the raw binary data to be treated in a different way, which means you have to be very confident that the reinterpretation makes sense.

**Arduino**
The line you identified in the Arduino file is fairly complicated when it's fully expanded, so we'll break it down a bit. As I think you've identified, it's defining a macro called `F()`, and that macro takes a parameter called `string_literal`.

As the name suggests, it's intended to be used with a string literal, `F("like this")`. Under the surface, the compiler treats a string literal as a pointer to an array of characters; or in other words, `char *`.

Inside the `F()` macro, the string literal is put into another macro, called `PSTR()`. That basically adds a whole bunch of other stuff which tells the compiler to store the string data in program space (where the sketch lives on your Arduino) rather than SRAM (where the variables live).

At this point, the `reinterpret_cast` comes into play. All the stuff in `PSTR()` is important, but it doesn't really affect the data type being seen by the cast. You can basically imagine it acting something like this:

```
char *ptr = "my string data";
reinterpret_cast<const __FlashStringHelper *>(ptr);
```

`__FlashStringHelper` is a class, which means its type is unrelated to `char *`. That's why we need to reinterpret it, so the compiler knows that we're taking responsibility for the safety of the operation. When the result of the cast is used, it will act like a pointer to a `__FlashStringHelper` object, meaning its methods can be used to access/process the string data.

In reality, no instance of `__FlashStringHelper` is actually created. The underlying data is still just our string literal. This is one of the interesting aspects of C++ -- you can actually call methods of an object which doesn't exist, as long as the object doesn't try to access non-existent member data.

Comment: Many thanks to you Mr Bloomfield: very clear explanation, now I'm a step further!

Answer (score 2):

`reinterpret_cast` operator is used for typecasting.It is to convert one pointer type to another.

Here `PSTR` is typecasted (converted) to `__FlashStringHelper*`